# Currying on first argument group

Tags: scala, currying

I have found currying nicer than partial application or implicits for a certain scenario. However I have not found a way to curry for an argument group that is the first in a list of argument groups.

E.g. take an original function:

`def a(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y`

It is easy to fix the first argument a la 
`def b = a(3)_`

But how can you fix the second one, and only the second one, instead?

Answer (score 4):

Type ascription works in this case:

```
scala> def a(a: Int)(b: Int) = a + b
a: (a: Int)(b: Int)Int

scala> a(_: Int)(3)
res12: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> res12(2)
res13: Int = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ordinary function for that:

```
def b(x: Int) = a(x)(3)
```